# How to mount a EBS in Cloudify after the creation of a VM

Tags: cloudify

I want to share some data with my VMs thanks to a mounted EBS.
How can I say to Cloudify that every created VM should have additional mounted EBS?

(I'm talking about EBS in the case of Amazon EC2, but I want to do the same with OpenStack, and other IaaS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ec2, you would need to set the template options in the template section of the cloud configuration file as follows:

```
options ([
"securityGroups" : ["default"]as String[],
"keyPair" : "XXXXX",
"blockDeviceMappings": [new org.jclouds.ec2.domain.BlockDeviceMapping.MapEBSSnapshotToDevice("/dev/sda1/","aa", 20, true) ] ])
```

Cloudify uses the [jclouds](http://www.jclouds.org/) multi-cloud library to handle API calls to amazon services. For more details on using EBS with EC2, see:

- http://demobox.github.com/jclouds-maven-site-1.4.0/1.4.0/jclouds-multi/apidocs/org/jclouds/ec2/domain/BlockDeviceMapping.MapEBSSnapshotToDevice.html
- http://demobox.github.com/jclouds-maven-site-1.4.0/1.4.0/jclouds-multi/apidocs/org/jclouds/ec2/domain/BlockDeviceMapping.MapNewVolumeToDevice.html

Please note that these settings are specific to EC2 and are not portable across clouds.

With regards to Openstack, The Cloudify Openstack cloud driver does not currently support using volumes, the openstack EBS equivalent. This is accurate for version 2.1.1 and 2.2 of Cloudify, though this feature is expected to become available in the near future.

Comment: Thanks! I know that you implemented your own OpenStack driver, but JClouds should also handle OpenStack. Is it possible to mount EBS equivalent in OpenStack using the JClouds driver instead of the OpenStack driver ? (until the next version of Cloudify of course)

Comment: The version of jclouds bundled with Cloudify is 1.4.0, and it does not support the latest versions of Openstack. The 1.5.0 release will include additional Openstack support so we will be adding it when it goes GA.